# Company is letting me go because they are closing, but they are still operating?

Tags: ethics, united-kingdom, layoff

My previous company stated that they are closing as they could not pay their creditors and as a result I was told I no longer work there. Since then, the company is still operating and providing services.

Do I have any recourse to regain my job? Does this appear to be grounds for unfair dismissal?

The country is the UK.

Comment: How long ago were you dismissed?  did they provide you with any documentation when you were dismissed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to The Workplace.  We can't answer questions about whether something is legal or you have recourse, sorry.  If you have a question about how (or whether) to talk with somebody at your ex-exmployer about it or how to get your job back since they haven't actually closed, that could be on-topic.

Comment: Note that they could have declared you surplus even if they were just restructuring or reorganizing, at least in the US... unless your contract says otherwise. It isn't clear that you're any better protected in this case. It also isn't clear that forcing them to rehire you, if possible, would lead to a good work situation...

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't imply legal advice (even in your head).

I would doubt you have any real recourse.  The likelihood is that the original company has been wound up as bust, the owner has started a new company and is now trading in place of the bust one (possibly buying the assets/name for a nominal fee).  It can be done (if you ever watch Watchdog you'll see it happen all the time), the company will have one name, but be trading as the defunct one.  Technically it is a different company so you have no claim, the job is gone as the company is bust, and there would be no assets to claim from either.

Given the owner has done this, I would suggest you just want to keep away anyway, next sign of trouble it'll happen again.

For example, here's a question on a UK accountancy site on doing just this:

[Closing down a limited company and start trading under a new company](http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/anyanswers/question/closing-down-limited-company-and-start-trading-under-new-company)

The advice was as follows

> As long as there are no personal guarantees, then he can do this.
>
> Putting ethics aside:
>
> Form NewCo (as Tosie says, totally different name to the old company)
>
> Open NewCo bank account
>
> If there are any assets (van, tools etc) sell these to NewCo at a reasonable market value. He will have to transfer the funds to OldCo and use these to distribute to creditors (or, in reality, it will get absorbed by the o/draft).
>
> Start trading in NewCo.
>
> etc...

Comment: Have a look on company house to check what they did.

Comment: For the sceptical, here's an a question and answer on an accountancy site (UK) on doing just this http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/anyanswers/question/closing-down-limited-company-and-start-trading-under-new-company

Comment: I would remind everyone of the "Be nice" policy.  Please keep it professional and polite.